# HTML Tag Position Ends preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

Here's a weird wrench that I'm dealing with at the moment. I've been back and forth with it, using a variety of regular expressions, spacing and quote variations but there seems to only be an issue with the placement of the closing `</a>` tag.

I've built a RegEx parser (I know) to grab tags from HTML output and trigger custom closures for each from a library of what we call "shortcodes". It'll just swap out the tag for the closure's return value, and if the closure doesn't exist, leave the tag in place.

When that `</a>` is placed on the same line as the tag I'm grabbing, it causes `preg_replace_callback` to fail. When I add a line break, everything works flawlessly. We're using these tags all over the place as a central part of our template system and they're working wonderfully in every other instance.

So my question is... why?! Is this a bug or am I the bug?

**EDIT:** Updated pattern to limit reluctancy. Closing `</a>` tag still kills the process. (@Alan Moore)

**EDIT 2:** So, the regex was the culprit. It was pulling in the content beyond the tag on the same line on some cases, but this pattern solved the problem - `'#\[\s*(\w[^\]\s]*)(.*?)\s*\]#i'`.

**Failing HTML**

```
<div>
    <a href="[ make_url post_id='200' ]">Some Link</a>
</div>
```

**Successful HTML**

```
<div>
    <a href="[ make_url post_id='200' ]">
        Some Link
    </a>
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
    <a href="[ make_url post_id='200' ]">Some Link
    </a>
</div>
```

**PHP**

Nothing fancy, and even when I dumb it down to the basics it still fails.

```
$content = 'HTML output from an output buffer';
//$old_pattern = '#\[\s*?(\w+?(?:\.?\w+?)*?(?=\s|\]))(.+)*?\s*?\]#i';
$pattern = '#\[\s*(\w+(?:\.?\w+)*(?=\s|\]))(.+)\s*\]#i';

$content = preg_replace_callback( $pattern, function( $matches ) {
    // Do things with the matches
}, $content );

// Send content back to the template
return $content;
```

Comment: What's with all the `*?` and/or `(.+)*?` ? What are they supposed to achieve?

Comment: They're supposed to account for user inconsistency, so if someone uses multiple spaces before the tag's slug (in this case `make_url`) the tag still gets picked up. `(.+)*?` is grabbing all the content after the slug and before the closing `]`, which gets parsed later to grab the params. This could probably be written more efficiently, I'm still pretty new to RegEx.

Comment: As a matter of fact, all those question marks are making your regex much, *much* less efficient than it should be.  Blindly making everything reluctant like that can easily result in [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't aware of catastrophic backtracking. I've altered the pattern to `\[\s*(\w+(?:\.?\w+)*(?=\s|\]))(.+)\s*\]` which still picks up everything I need. Any idea why the placement of the closing `</a>` tag might kill the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the regex was the culprit. It was pulling in the content beyond the tag on the same line on some cases, but this pattern solved the problem - `#\[\s*(\w[^\]\s]*)(.*?)\s*\]#i`.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm does something as basic as this not work for you?

```
/<a.*?(\[.*?\]).*?>.*?<\/a>/is
```

E.g.

```
$matches = null;
$result = 
    preg_match_all('/<a.*?(\[.*?\]).*?>.*?<\/a>/is', '
        <div>
            <a href="[ make_url post_id=\'200\' ]">Some Link</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="[ make_url post_id=\'200\' ]">
                Some Link
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="[ make_url post_id=\'200\' ]">Some Link
            </a>
        </div>
    ', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/PM70m1

Comment: I'm not looking to grab the content within the `<a></a>` tags, I'm looking to grab the custom tag (`[ make_url ]`) and all of it's parameters, which can be a few at times. e.g. `[ make_url post_id='200' template='default' ]`

Comment: @rpnzl is that infor only stored in attributes? also see my updated answer.

Comment: The tags are meant to be used anywhere in the HTML, not necessarily within HTML tag attributes or with an `<a>` tag. The existing RegEx and parsing methods I have work great everywhere _except_ this strange, singular instance. The only thing I could isolate is the closing `</a>` tag - when it's on the same line as the `[ make_url ]` tag, `preg_replace_callback` fails. When I add a line break, everything is fine. I'm not looking for a RegEx solution as much as I'm looking for why the line break matters here, unless RegEx is the reason, of course.

Comment: @rpnzl you need to give us more information on where and how your `tags` are placed: E.g. are these value `<br[foo]/>` `<div>[ some <hr/> ]<div>` `<p data-hey="['look ma, I\'m JSON',47,'\'\\\'[]]][']"></p>` etc...

Comment: The basic structure of a tag is `[ slug attr="value" ]` with any number of potential attributes. They are used to output strings or HTML, so there will never be HTML within a tag like `[ slug <hr/> ]`. `<div>[ slug ]</div>` and `<p class="[ slug ]">` are valid examples.